# JavaScript : Search bar taking into consideration order of letters

Tags: javascript, function, search

it's my first post in stackOverflow (don't be monsters please hehe). I'm looking for advice or tips for a function for a search bar. I already using this:

```
    for (i = 0; i < taskButton.length; i++) {
    //if there is a match 
        if (tasks[i].toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        //display the match
          taskButton[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          //hide the mismatch
          taskButton[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

But with indexOf, is there is a space character in the string, for example, it will show all the strings with a space. I want to improve this search function taking into consideration the order of each letter.
Thank you per advance guys !

Comment: *I want to improve this search function taking into consideration the order of each letter* What does this mean? Do you mean you only want a match if a character at index `index` in the `filter` is also in `tasks[i]` at that index?

Comment: @j0nCvn do you want to match starting from index 0 inside your text, not starting from anywhere?

Comment: @tudor.gergely yep that's it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `startsWith` instead of `indexOf`:

```
for (let i = 0; i < taskButton.length; i++) {
  taskButton[i].style.display = tasks[i].toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)
    ? ''
    : 'none';
}
```

You can use the conditional operator to make the code more concise, as above, and also make sure to declare your `i` variable - if you don't declare a variable, you'll implicitly assign to the global object (which is messy), *or*, an error will be thrown, if you're in strict mode.

Comment: Awesome, it's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much for your help and advice